# Load local PDF with ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I just want to show a PDF that is found within the project directory.

I did read the online documentation [render-local-pdf-file](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/blob/HEAD/README.md#render-local-pdf-file) but still, I was not able to make this work.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.scss'],
})
export class MessageComponent{
  src: string = '../confirmation.pdf';
}
```

and here is how I implemented it within the template

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="src" style="display: block;">
  </pdf-viewer>
```

If I use the pdf found in the example ("https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf") the viewer works.

Why does it make a difference if I use a local file agains an URL for the PDF?

The error I am getting is the following:
`404 Not Found XHR GET http://localhost:4200/confirmation.pdf`

The file is found one level above the message component:

```
confirmation.pdf
- message
 - message.component.html
 - message.component.ts
```

Comment: Put the PDF in the assets folder and read it from there.

Comment: @R.Richards why would this make any difference? But it worked...

Comment: Random files dropped in the root of any Angular CLI project will not get packaged and served, *unless* they are in the assets folder.